# SpecFlow WebDriver Errors on closing or quiting the WebDriver

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver, nunit, specflow

I'm testing a website with `Specflow` and `WebDriver`.
I'm using events of specflow to start and quit the Driver. I start the Driver in `[BeforeFeature]` and quit it in `[AfterFeature]`.

I use a static Common Class to hold the Driver and have the methods to operate it.

The problem happens after all tests are run on a feature and the next feature starts to run. I get the following errors.:

If in the `[AfterFeature]` I do a **Driver.Close()** I get the error:

```
    -> error: Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:7055
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor.cs:line 91
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.Internal.ExtensionConnection.Execute(Command commandToExecute) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Firefox\Internal\ExtensionConnection.cs:line 128
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(DriverCommand driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 795
```

If I do a **Driver.Quit()** I get the error:

```
-> error: Cannot deserialize JSON object into type 'System.String'. Line 1, position 35.
```

If I don't close or quit the driver, Every Features run with no problem, but I get lots of opened Firefox Windows.

My code is:

```
[Binding]
public class Events
{
    [BeforeFeature]
    public static void BeforeFeature()
    {
        Common.CreateDriver();
    }

    [AfterFeature]
    public static void AfterFeature()
    {
        Common.QuitDriver();
    }
}
```

And...

```
public static class Common
{
    public static IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }        

    public static void CreateDriver(){            
        Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));        
    }

    public static void CloseDriver()
    {
        Driver.Close();
    }

    public static void QuitDriver()
    {
        Driver.Quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out what the problem was. 
I will put it here for future reference.

The problem was in the way I was reading the Driver on my BaseWebObject, the father of all PageObjects.

I had this:

```
    public class BaseWebObject
{        
    protected static IWebDriver Driver = Common.Driver;

}
```

This Fails because the Driver will only be read once in the static constructor.

To make it work I must read the Driver at the instantiation time, so in the instance constructor like so:

```
    public class BaseWebObject
{        
    protected static IWebDriver Driver;

    public BaseWebObject()
    {
        Driver = Common.Driver;
    }    
}
```